# Let's provide some assistance with clarifying what's being asked in this Meta.SE question

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad, ediciones, meta

A question was asked at Meta.SE that could be relevant for us.  The asker had some trouble explaining their question.  I think I kind of get it, but I can't help yet because my one-week suspension there hasn't ended yet.

Perhaps some other people could help by editing the question there.  Here's the question:

[Is there a solution for problems with communities for languages other than English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338936/287826)

I'm giving the new tag a try "petición-de-funcionalidad" because I think the OP there was expressing frustration with the difficulty their moderators are having implementing certain changes that had achieved consensus.

Comment: The OP for that question does not seem to have raised it on the site meta so I share everyone's perplexity about what they are asking.

Comment: @mdewey - I think I have some hunches about what they might be talking about. 
 But I've just looked around over there and can't find anything to cite as an example.  I thought to check their chat but they've got a million rooms and I don't know which one is the main one.  I've posted a question at their Meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8057/170215.  Hopefully someone there will see it....

Comment: Thank you for taking care about this site, but I actually don't understand the question you link at Meta.SE, so how can it be relevant here? If you think that something wrong actually happens with the sites in other languages apart from English, then we should indentify those problems first. What are your concerns about this site and the changes we should implement?